# Generate random numbers only with specific digits

Tags: python, random

How do I generate a random number from a specific set of digits? For example,
I want to generate numbers from the range `1-100,000` such that every number has only odd digits (for example: `111`, `1351`, `19711` etc..)

Using the random module I tried:

```
import random

rand = random.randint([1, 3, 5, 7, 9])
```

Is there any efficient way of doing it?
Thank you.

Comment: Removed your "update" from this question, since you've posted a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using list-comprehension:

```
>>> random.sample([i for i in range(1,100_001) if all([int(x)%2==1 for x in str(i)])], 4)
[3115, 75359, 53159, 31771]
```

---

As pointed out in the comments below, the above code becomes more and more inefficient the larger the numbers get, due to all numbers being checked if each of them includes only odd-numbers. That includes numbers that are even.

IF we add another filter to first remove all even-numbers we reduce the amounts of comparisons that are being made by about a third.

Here is a quick comparison between the two:

```
import datetime
import random

def timer(var):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = datetime.datetime.now()
        result = var()
        print(f"Elapsed time: {datetime.datetime.now()-start}")
        return result
    return wrapper

@timer
def allNumbers():
    return random.sample([i for i in range(1, 1_000_001) if all([int(x) % 2 == 1 for x in str(i)])], 4)

@timer
def oddNumbers():
    return random.sample([i for i in [x for x in range(1, 1_000_001) if x % 2 == 1] if all([int(x) % 2 == 1 for x in str(i)])], 4)

print("Calling allNumbers:")
print(allNumbers())
print("Calling oddNumbers:")
print(oddNumbers())
```

Output:

```
Calling allNumbers:
Elapsed time: 0:00:05.119071
[153539, 771197, 199379, 751557]
Calling oddNumbers:
Elapsed time: 0:00:02.978188
[951919, 1399, 199515, 791393]
```

Comment: `True if int(x)%2==1 else False...` can be replaced by `int(x)%2==1`

Comment: Awesome that works for me! (Can accept in 5 minutes..)

Comment: This works, but it will be rather inefficient for larger ranges.

Comment: @SvenMarnach What is more efficient in your opinion? Hampus' answer or yatu's ?

Comment: This is quite overkill. You'll be looping an unnecessary amount of times sampling from *wrong*  numbers which have some even digit

Comment: @yatu I've updated the code with additional filtering, and tests. It's a brute-force way to solve the issue at hand as it loops over all digits, and I definitely don't think it's the best solution at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've written an update which is quite harder, and I am stuck because I don't know how to make sure there are at least 3 unique digits... Thank you again!

Answer (score 5):

One way could be to define a list of odds from which to sample, but keeping in mind the how likely it *should* be for a number to be sampled randomly. Since there are ten times as many 2 digit numbers than 1 digit numbers, we need to set the weights of these sampling sizes according to this logic.

Following this reasoning, we could use `numpy.random.choice`, which allows for sampling from a list following a probability distribution:

```
from numpy.random import choice

odds = ['1','3','5','7','9']

n_digits = 5 # up to 99999 for ex
range_digits = list(range(1,n_digits))

weights = [5**i for i in range_digits]
weights_sum = sum(weights)
probs = [i/weights_sum for i in weights]

sizes = choice(range_digits,size=n,p=probs)
[int(''.join(choice(odds,size))) for size in sizes]
# [3151, 3333, 1117, 7577, 1955, 1793, 5713, 1595, 5195, 935]
```

---

Let's check the generated distribution for `10_000` samples:

```
from collections import Counter

sizes = choice(range_digits,size=10_000,p=probs)
out = [int(''.join(choice(odds,size))) for size in sizes]

Counter(len(str(i)) for i in out)
# Counter({4: 8099, 3: 1534, 2: 304, 1: 63})
```

Comment: This distorts the random distribution. One-digit numbers will be much more likely, since there are only 5 of them.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, This takes a random sample of `odds`, with up to size k=5. So size 1 samples will be as likely as size 4 or 5 @SvenMarnach

Comment: Yes, exactly, that's why it is distorted. There are only 5 numbers with one digit, and 25 with two digits, so number with two digits should be more likely.

Comment: That is a very good point @sven I totally missed that. Thanks

Comment: Maybe we there's some alternative which allows weights? @sven

Comment: `random.choices()` does allow weights.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/9bQ0s4 to see the distortion.

Comment: Yes it totally makes sense. I think an alternative could be to take random choices from a list of ints 1 to 5 as sizes  with probabilities `[10**i for i in range_digits]` normalized to add to 1 @sven

Comment: Updated @sven , I think it should be unbiased now. Though i think there's plenty room for improvement, not too convinced about performance either. I'd appreciate your feedback

Comment: It should be `5 ** i` instead of `10 ** i` for `i` digits. We have 5 choices for each digit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've written an update which is quite harder, and I am stuck because I don't know how to make sure there are at least 3 unique digits... Thank you again!

Comment: That is a new question. In such case I'd kindly encourage you to ask a new question here in SO, otherwise it could mislead future visitors @OnAndOff

Comment: @yatu I've opened a new one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62943065/generating-all-numbers-from-a-specific-set-with-at-least-n-unique-digits-in-pyth

Answer (score 0):

Given the range you want is 1 - 100,000 you will never pick 100,000 because it has even digits: 0.  Effectively your maximum allowed output is 99,999.  That is five digits.

Your output might have invisible leading zeros: 975 is allowed, which is effectively 00975.  Those leading zeros have to be allowed for in your code.

1. Pick how many leading zeros you have.  10% of the numbers in your range have a leading zero.  10% of those have a second leading zero. 10% of those (1 in 1,000) have a third leading zero and so on.  Five leading zeros is 0 output.  That is outside the allowed range, so you will need to start picking again.  That will only happen very rarely.
2. Once you know how many leading zeros there are, you know how many other digits you need.  Pick that many digits from the allowed digit list: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9].