# Generating all numbers from a specific set with at least N unique digits in Python 3.8.2

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I generate all numbers between `1-K` such that any number between them only contains these digits: `{1,3,5,7,9}` **and** they have at least 3 unique digits.

For example, these numbers are not allowed:
11, 1133333, 151322  (The first and second do contain only digits from `{1,3,5,7,9}` however they don't have **at least** 3 unique digits from this set. And the third one contains the digit 2 which is not in the set..

These numbers are O.K:
157, 1111157, 55591, 99913

What I have so far (Using this post: [Generate random numbers only with specific digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62931500/generate-random-numbers-only-with-specific-digits?noredirect=1#comment111307489_62931500) )
Using  yatu's kind answer:

```
from numpy.random import choice
odds = ['1','3','5','7','9']

n_digits = 6 # up to 99999 for ex
range_digits = list(range(1,n_digits))

weights = [5**i for i in range_digits]
weights_sum = sum(weights)
probs = [i/weights_sum for i in weights]

sizes = choice(range_digits,size=20,p=probs)
a = [int(''.join(choice(odds,size))) for size in sizes]
```

However 2 things I need to change:

1. I need to make sure the numbers contain at least 3 unique digits from `{1,3,5,7,9}`
2. I need to generate them in ascending order, and not use random picking.  That is, if the range is 100- 1000 then it would return: 137, 173, 317, 371 etc... until it hits 973 which is the biggest number that satisfies these conditions

Thank you so much! (Python 3.8.2)

Answer (score 1):

If the range of numbers is not too large, you can generate all/most of the numbers and filter out the ones that don't meet the requirements.

```
def requirement(n):
    s = set(str(n))
    return len(s) > 2 and len(s & {'0','2','4','6','8'}) == 0

numbers = filter(requirement, range(start | 1, end, 2))
```

If the range of numbers is large, this method can be inefficient.

Comment: The problem is that it returns for start=100 and end =1000 these numbers: {102, 104 etc..} which is not allowed + it does not check for 3 unique digits from the set

Comment: In the comment I said start should be an odd number.  I changed the code to `start | 1` to make sure it starts at an odd number.

Comment: But it still contains digits which are not in the set `{1,3,7,9}`

Comment: Doh. Had a set of integers ({0,2,...}) instead of a set of characters ({'0', '2', ...}).  Fixed.

Comment: Thank you! What about large numbers, how would you do that? Because I am dealing with very large numbers ( 8 - 10 digits even more) or this one is capable of dealing with it?

Answer (score 0):

If you use ascending order then it won't be random; if you use random picking then it won't be in ascending order.

One possibility is to use ascending order to generate likely candidate numbers and then weed out the unsuitable numbers.

Since you only allow 5 digits, [1, 3, 5, 7, 9] I suggest that you count ascending order in base 5 and map the five base 5 digits: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] onto your allowed odd base 10 digits.  So 42201 (base 5) maps to 95513 in odd-digit base 10.  That will be followed by 42202 (base 5) giving 95515 (base 10) and so on.

That gives ascending numbers using only your allowed digits.  You will have to test each number separately to see if it conforms to the three different digits rule.