# generate random numbers in specific range and using specific numbers?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

How to generate random numbers in specific range and using specific numbers?

Example
given numbers [7,8];
given range [100-900];
output must be one of them 777, 787, 788, 878, 877, 888 etc...

Help me

```
const randomGenerateNumber = (maxRange:number, minRange:number, numbers:number[]) => {
 //...what should i do in there??? Help me? Any Idea?
}
```

Comment: What you could do is generating random numbers within given range and checking if any of the given numbers is in the generated random numbers, remove the rest. Basic Approach.

Comment: You need to turn the problem round a bit,. First generate a list of the possible outcomes, then pick one of at random.

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't want random numbers. It seems that you want a set of numbers based on some rules. Random means something else.

If I understand well your question you want to generate all possible numbers containing only a set of digits from a range of numbers. Is this an accurate description?

If so, this is similar with what you want: [Generate random numbers only with specific digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62931500/generate-random-numbers-only-with-specific-digits)

**Edit:**

You are right, so you want only one number.
In javascript you could do something like this:

I edited the algorithm to take into account min and max in probably the most lazy way. I didn't take into account cases where numbers can't be generated, it will return undefined.

There are so many ways to do this. Your algorithm can work too and maybe more efficient but it seems to have an issue with 0, it will generate numbers with 0 even if it's not in the digits array.

```
function randomGenerateNumber(minRange, maxRange, digits){
    
    noTries = 0;
    while(noTries++ < 100000)
    {
        
        var num = 0;    
        //get a random number from your range
        len = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxRange - minRange) + minRange);
        //get the lenght of that random number
        len = len.toString().length;
        
        //generate a number with that length using only your set of digits
        while(len--)
        {
            num = num * 10 + digits[Math.floor(Math.random() * digits.length)];                         
        }
        
        if(num >= minRange && num<= maxRange)
        {
            return num;
            break;
        }                   
    }                   
}

//your testing cases
console.log(randomGenerateNumber(100,900,[7,8]))
console.log(randomGenerateNumber(299,300,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]));
```

Comment: No, i want random number. i want one of them 777, 787, 788, 878, 877, 888. not all of them only one of them

Comment: What about 778 or 887?

Comment: Your algorithm doesnt cover all condition. Example randomGenerateNumber(299,300, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]); In that condition it doesnt work output must be 299

Answer (score 0):

i did it. Is there any improvement. Little bit messy.

```
const getRandomNumber = (min: number, max: number, numbers: number[]): number => {
  if (numbers.length === 9) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  }
  let result = '';

  //split maxDigits 100 => [1, 0, 0]
  const maxDigits = max
    .toString()
    .split('')
    .map(i => parseInt(i, 10));

  //split minDigits 100 => [1, 0, 0]
  const minDigits = min
    .toString()
    .split('')
    .map(i => parseInt(i, 10));

  //length of random number [minDigit, maxDigit] inclusive
  const randomDigit = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxDigits.length - minDigits.length + 1) + minDigits.length);

  let alreadyHigh = false;

  let alreadyLow = false;

  let equal = true;

  //4 conditions

  //1. minDigits.length === maxDigits.length
  //2. randomDigit === minDigits.length
  //3. randomDigit === maxDigits.length
  //4. randomDigit > minDigits.length && randomDigit < maxDigits.length

  for (let i = 0; i < randomDigit; i++) {
    const numbersToUse = i === 0 ? numbers : [...numbers, 0];
    let availableNumbers = [];

    if (minDigits.length === maxDigits.length) {
      if (equal) {
        for (let k = 0; k < numbersToUse.length; k++) {
          if (minDigits[i] > maxDigits[i]) {
            if (numbersToUse[k] >= 0 && numbersToUse[k] <= maxDigits[i]) {
              availableNumbers.push(numbersToUse[k]);
            }
          } else if (numbersToUse[k] >= minDigits[i] && numbersToUse[k] <= maxDigits[i]) {
            availableNumbers.push(numbersToUse[k]);
          } else {
            availableNumbers.push(maxDigits[i]);
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (!alreadyHigh) {
          for (let k = 0; k < numbersToUse.length; k++) {
            if (numbersToUse[k] >= minDigits[i]) {
              availableNumbers.push(numbersToUse[k]);
            }
          }
        } else {
          availableNumbers = numbersToUse;
        }
      }
    } else if (randomDigit === minDigits.length) {
      if (!alreadyHigh) {
        for (let k = 0; k < numbersToUse.length; k++) {
          if (numbersToUse[k] >= minDigits[i]) {
            availableNumbers.push(numbersToUse[k]);
          }
        }
      } else {
        availableNumbers = numbersToUse;
      }
    } else if (randomDigit === maxDigits.length) {
      if (!alreadyLow) {
        for (let k = 0; k < numbersToUse.length; k++) {
          if (numbersToUse[k] <= maxDigits[i]) {
            availableNumbers.push(numbersToUse[k]);
          }
        }
      } else {
        availableNumbers = numbersToUse;
      }
    } else {
      availableNumbers = numbersToUse;
    }

    availableNumbers = [...new Set(availableNumbers)];
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableNumbers.length);
    result += `${availableNumbers[randomIndex]}`;

    alreadyHigh = !alreadyHigh ? availableNumbers[randomIndex] > minDigits[i] : true;
    alreadyLow = !alreadyLow ? availableNumbers[randomIndex] < maxDigits[i] : true;
    equal = equal ? availableNumbers[randomIndex] === maxDigits[i] : false;
  }
  return parseInt(result, 10);
};
```